# receiving Boolean variable with json request in volley

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, android-volley

I'm trying to make a request to MVC Server with web-api using volley in android, I want to send the parameters of the function as a JSON (the request body), so I used JSONRequest to make the call but the problem is the JSONRequest forces you to Use the Response.Listner, and the function I'm calling returns a Boolean variable , so I'm getting casting error every time I make the call

I tried to make a custom call that accepts Boolean but now I'm getting error 400 and I don't know why, is there a way to make the jsonRequest receive Boolean? and if not, what is the solution ?

the function I used the first time:

```
public void getJSON(String controllerName,String actionName, JSONObject requestBody,Response.Listener<JSONObject> success,Response.ErrorListener error){
    String url = makeURL(controllerName,actionName);
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,requestBody,success,error);
    request.setTag(APP_TAG);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

and here is my second trial with custom request (getting error 400):

```
public void getBooleanRequest(String controllerName,String actionName, final HashMap<String,String> body, final HashMap<String,String> header, final Response.Listener<Boolean> success,Response.ErrorListener error){
    String url = makeURL(controllerName,actionName);
    Request<Boolean> request = new Request<Boolean>(Request.Method.POST,url,error) {
        @Override
        protected Response<Boolean> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            return Response.success(true, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }

        @Override
        protected void deliverResponse(Boolean response) {
            success.onResponse(response);
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return body;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            return header;
        }
    };
    request.setTag(APP_TAG);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: You can create a custom request, then parseNetworkResponse to get desired data (boolean value)

Comment: You mean override the jsonrequest response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try my following sample code:

```
private class BooleanRequest extends Request<Boolean> {
    private final Response.Listener<Boolean> mListener;
    private final Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;
    private final String mRequestBody;

    private final String PROTOCOL_CHARSET = "utf-8";
    private final String PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE = String.format("application/json; charset=%s", PROTOCOL_CHARSET);

    public BooleanRequest(int method, String url, String requestBody, Response.Listener<Boolean> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
        this.mRequestBody = requestBody;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<Boolean> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        Boolean parsed;
        try {
            parsed = Boolean.valueOf(new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers)));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            parsed = Boolean.valueOf(new String(response.data));
        }
        return Response.success(parsed, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }

    @Override
    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
        return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(Boolean response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return PROTOCOL_CONTENT_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        try {
            return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes(PROTOCOL_CHARSET);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s",
                    mRequestBody, PROTOCOL_CHARSET);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your Activity:

```
   try {
        JSONObject jsonBody;
        jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        jsonBody.put("Title", "Android Demo");
        jsonBody.put("Author", "BNK");
        jsonBody.put("Date", "2015/08/28");
        String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();
        BooleanRequest booleanRequest = new BooleanRequest(0, url, requestBody, new Response.Listener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Boolean response) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, String.valueOf(response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(booleanRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this methods ignores the fact that I need to send my request body as a JSON