# How to debug "json parsing error: Value true at error of type java.lang.Boolean cannot be converted to JSONObject"

Tags: java, android, json

I am making android app with gcm integration for group chatting and messages broadcasting. But when I'm executing it, application showing an error:

> json parsing error: Value true at error of type java.lang.Boolean cannot be converted to JSONObject

`LoginActivity.java`:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private EditText inputName, inputEmail;
    private TextInputLayout inputLayoutName, inputLayoutEmail;
    private Button btnEnter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**
         * Check for login session. It user is already logged in
         * redirect him to main activity
         * */
        if (MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefManager().getUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        inputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_name);
        inputLayoutEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_email);
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
        btnEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_enter);

        inputName.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputName));
        inputEmail.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputEmail));

        btnEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                login();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * logging in user. Will make http post request with name, email
     * as parameters
     */
    private void login() {
        if (!validateName()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!validateEmail()) {
            return;
        }

        final String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        final String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                EndPoints.LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "response: " + response);

                try {



                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                    // check for error flag
                    if (obj.getBoolean("error") == false) {
                        // user successfully logged in

                        JSONObject userObj = obj.getJSONObject("user");
                        User user = new User(userObj.getString("user_id"),
                                userObj.getString("name"),
                                userObj.getString("email"));

                        // storing user in shared preferences
                        MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefManager().storeUser(user);

                        // start main activity
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                        finish();

                    } else {
                        // login error - simply toast the message
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + obj.getJSONObject("error").getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json parse error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                Log.e(TAG, "Volley error: " + error.getMessage() + ", code: " + networkResponse);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Volley error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("email", email);

                Log.e(TAG, "params: " + params.toString());
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Adding request to request queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
    }

    private void requestFocus(View view) {
        if (view.requestFocus()) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    // Validating name
    private boolean validateName() {
        if (inputName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            inputLayoutName.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_name));
            requestFocus(inputName);
            return false;
        } else {
            inputLayoutName.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        return true;
    }

    // Validating email
    private boolean validateEmail() {
        String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty() || !isValidEmail(email)) {
            inputLayoutEmail.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_email));
            requestFocus(inputEmail);
            return false;
        } else {
            inputLayoutEmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }

    private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private View view;
        private MyTextWatcher(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.input_name:
                    validateName();
                    break;
                case R.id.input_email:
                    validateEmail();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: post the value of `response`.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261410/receiving-boolean-variable-with-json-request-in-volley/32261896#32261896

Answer (score 0):

Because the `response` you are getting it not properly formatted for Json conversion.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
```

Its returning `boolean` which you are trying to convert into `JSONObject`.

Edit 1: It might also occur that there is problem while fetching `boolean`.

Try to fetch it like this:

```
 jsonObject.optBoolean("error");
```

Comment: so,what shoud i add so that it could get converted into JSONObject ?

Comment: You are doing the right thing, but volley is returning boolean value not a json value. Print the response and see if that's what you are expecting?

Comment: it will be more helpful bro, if u can help me with a shot of code,

Comment: For that you will have to post the value of `response` which you are getting in volley onResponse.

Comment: This is what i m getting in logcat .                                                                                                                    " params: {email=nuk@gmail.com, name=nik}
 {   "error":true,"message":"Oops! An error occurred while registereing"}
           json parsing error: Value true at error of type java.lang.Boolean cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: this is the response: `{"error":true,"message":"Oops! An error occurred while registereing"}` ?

Comment: Only this much error i m getting in log.                                                                                                                  " params: {email=nuk@gmail.com, name=nik}
/LoginActivity: response: {"error":true,"message":"Oops! An error occurred while registereing"}
E/LoginActivity: json parsing error: Value true at error of type java.lang.Boolean cannot be converted to JSONObject ".

Comment: Anyway if you want stack trace, get it here like this:
`catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }`

Comment: still Bro, Error is same .